# excel nested if and statement - can't see why it won't work

Tags: excel, if-statement

I have these if and statements.  They all work.  However, when I nest them, they don't but I don't know why.

I have two columns:  R and S

S contains a time stamp and I need to evaluate if the reaction times in column R fall between to specific values.  E.g. in statement 'A' I'm evaluating if reaction times occurred between timestamps 750812 and 859723.  Below these statements are my attempt to nest the statements so that I can just run the code down the column without having to separately check.  Kindly let me know if you can spot the problem.

```
=IF(AND(S2>$AB$5,S2<=$AC$5),1,0)       A
=IF(AND(S27>$AB$6,S27<=$AC$6),2,0)     B
=IF(AND(S45>$AB$7,S45<=$AC$7),3,0)     C
=IF(AND(S69>$AB$8,S69<=$AC$8),4,0)     D
=IF(AND(S85>$AB$9,S85<=$AC$9),5,0)     E
```

Nested:

```
=IF(AND(S2>$AB$5,S2<=$AC$5),1,IF(AND(S27>$AB$6,S27<=$AC$6),2,IF(AND(S45>$AB$7,S45<=$AC$7),3,IF(AND(S69>$AB$8,S69<=$AC$8),4,IF(AND(S85>$AB$9,S85<=$AC$9),5,0)))))
```

Comment: What does not work about the statements?

Comment: it works for some values but not others.  It gave me "1" for values from 751267 to 859723 as expected but zero for other values.  So for 863395, the if statement should have returned a "2" and for 1079459 it should have returned a "3", etc. I can't figure it out.

Comment: These are the values:

Comment: A: 750812 to 860333.40
B: 860333.40 to 969854.80
C: 969854.80 to 1079376.20
D: 1079376.20 to 1188897.60
E: 1188897.60  to 1298419.00

Comment: Please, edit your original question, and add this new info, and your question will be more easy to understand. Help comunnity to help you :) A data example of your input and your expected output wil help for sure

Comment: Thanks but it's not the best way to solve my problem anyway, I just thought there was something in the syntax like a missing bracket or quotations but if that's not it I need to find a better solution.  It's the sort of thing I could do in R if I knew how to program :-/

Comment: "*it works for some values but not others. It gave me "1" for values from 751267 to 859723 as expected but zero for other values*"  Are you certain you entered these **other values** in the correct cell?  In other words, did you enter `863395` in `S27` and `1079459` in `S45`?

Comment: I did, but it's not the best solution to the problem. What I really need to do is create a looped solution, but I'm not good with that. I'm having a try with R at the moment. Thank you so much for your willingness to help.  Really appreciate it :-)

Comment: Instead of nesting all those `IF` statements, take a look at `IFS` which is a bit more like a case switch and allows you to go through multiple conditions in one. Is surely easier to debug than 5 levels of nesting, too :)

Comment: Thanks for that Alex, I'll give that a try.